# Elevator simulator

Tags: python, object-oriented, community-challenge

I have an elevator simulator. After launching the script it always waits for the user input. The user can press *get number*, where *number* is a floor where the passenger is located.

Note that one of the command line arguments is `floor` (the maximum number of floors in building). When the passenger is in the elevator he can push one or more buttons and the elevator should go to the nearest floor and so on.

I know that OOP usage is poor here and I need advice how I can improve it.

#### Arguments:

- `speed` - the speed of the elevator
- `doors` - doors opening and closing speed
- `floor_height` - height of the floor

```
import argparse
import sys
import time
import select
import numpy as np

def createParser ():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument ('-floor', '--floor')
    parser.add_argument ('-floor_height', '--floor_height')
    parser.add_argument ('-speed', '--speed')
    parser.add_argument ('-doors', '--doors')

    return parser

parser = createParser()
namespace = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
timeout = 3.0

class Floor:
  def __init__(self, max_floor, height):
    self.max_floor = int(max_floor)
    self.start_floor = 1
    self.current = 1
    self.current2 = 1
    self.height = height
    self.dest_floor = []

  def check_start_floor(self, new_start_floor):
    if new_start_floor > self.max_floor or new_start_floor < 1:
      print("Floor number is incorrect")
    else:
      self.start_floor = new_start_floor

  def calculate_multiple_floors(self, new_floors):
    a = np.array(new_floors)
    while len(a) > 0:
      i = np.argmin(np.abs(a-self.current2))
      self.dest_floor.append(a[i])
      a=np.delete(a, i)
    for j in self.dest_floor[:]:
      if j > int(self.max_floor):
        self.dest_floor.remove(j)
      elif j < 1:
        self.dest_floor.remove(j)

  def calculate_one_floor(self, new_floors):
    self.dest_floor.append(new_floors)
    if self.dest_floor[0] > int(self.max_floor):
      self.dest_floor = []


class Elevator:
  def __init__(self, speed, doors):
    self.speed = int(speed)
    self.doors = int(doors)

  def route(self, floor_height, speed):
    return int(floor_height)/int(speed)

  def move_up(self, route, floor):
    while floor.current < floor.start_floor:
      print("current floor: %d" % floor.current)
      floor.current += 1
      time.sleep(route)
    print("current floor: %d" % floor.current)
    print("elevator opens the doors")
    time.sleep(self.doors)
    print("elevator opened the doors")
    floor.current2 = floor.current

  def move_down(self, route, floor):
    while floor.current > floor.start_floor:
      print("current floor: %d" % floor.current)
      floor.current -= 1
      time.sleep(route)
    print("current floor: %d" % floor.current)
    print("elevator opens the doors")
    time.sleep(self.doors)
    print("elevator opened the doors")
    floor.current2 = floor.current

  def press_button(self, route, floor):
    print("elevator closes the doors")
    time.sleep(self.doors)
    print("elevator closes the doors")
    
    for j in floor.dest_floor[:]:

      if floor.current2 < j:
        while floor.current2 < j:
          print("current floor: %d" % floor.current2)
          floor.current2 += 1
          time.sleep(route)
        print("current floor: %d" % floor.current2)
        print("elevator opens the doors")
        time.sleep(self.doors)
        print("elevator opened the doors")
        print("elevator closes the doors")
        time.sleep(self.doors)
        print("elevator closed the doors")          

      elif floor.current2 > j:
        while floor.current2 > j:
          print("current floor: %d" % floor.current2)
          floor.current2 -= 1
          time.sleep(route)
        print("current floor: %d" % floor.current2)
        print("elevator opens the doors")
        time.sleep(self.doors)
        print("elevator opened the doors")
        print("elevator closes the doors")
        time.sleep(self.doors)
        print("elevator closed the doors")
      floor.dest_floor.remove(j)


def main():
  elevator = Elevator(namespace.speed, namespace.doors)
  floor = Floor(namespace.floor, namespace.floor_height)
  route = elevator.route(floor.height, elevator.speed)

  while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
    if len(rlist):
        command = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')

        if 'get' in command: # passenger call an elevator
          floor.check_start_floor(int(command.split(' ')[1]))
        elif 'set' in command: # passenger push button or buttons inside
          if len(command.split(' ')) > 2:
            b = [int(x) for x in command.split(' ')[1:]]
            floor.calculate_multiple_floors(b)
          else:
            floor.calculate_one_floor(int(command.split(' ')[1]))

    if floor.start_floor != 0:
      if floor.current < floor.start_floor:
        elevator.move_up(route, floor)
      elif floor.current > floor.start_floor:
        elevator.move_down(route, floor)

    if floor.dest_floor != []:
      elevator.press_button(route, floor)

main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three types of elevator control systems that I am aware of: rheostat, push-button, and destination-control. Your simulator does not simulate any one of those three types.

I suggest you try to implement a simulation closer to whatever elevator model you actually have in mind. Be LITERAL! If you want to simulate a push-button elevator, with [UP] and [DN] buttons on each floor, then do that! Create floors. Give them an up and a down button. Give them lights. Provide an elevator cab interface with buttons, and the super-irritating "door open" and "door close" buttons that don't appear to do anything.

Next, implement the *strategy pattern* to make the elevator control algorithm pluggable. There are a number of competing algorithms for elevators, so why not support more than one?

You might consider threads, or async, in order to support some simultaneity: you want to be able to handle buttons pressed while the elevator is moving.

Finally, move your argument parsing setup into `main()`. And get rid of `namespace` - use `args` or something more comprehensible.